# How do i sort my events with regards to "grandchildren's" date

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6

We’ve got an EF6 MVC3 codeFirst-site. Our **Events** may have a collection of **EventRallies**. And the EventRallies may have a collection of **EventOccasions**

I want to order them so that events with any future occasions is at the top, followed by events where  all occasions are in the past, and then events that doesn´t have any rallies or occasinons tied to them.

The following attempt results in an :System.ArgumentException: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable- error ;)

```
return context.Events.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == id).
Include(x => x.EventRallies).
Include(x => x.EventRallies.Select(e => e.EventOccasions)).
OrderBy(x => x.EventRallies.OrderByDescending(d=>d.EventOccasions.FirstOrDefault().Date)).ToList();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SelectMany` to get one list of all `EventOccasion`s of one `Event`. Select their dates. This list can be ordered by date (descending). The first date in this list is the ordering key for the Events.

If you order by this date key descending, the future events will come first, then the past events, followed by the events without any occasion.

```
context.Events.Where(x => x.OrganizationId == id)
.Include(x => x.EventRallies)
.Include(x => x.EventRallies.Select(e => e.EventOccasions))
.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventRallies.SelectMany(d => d.EventOccasions)
    .Select(occ => occ.Date)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d)
    .FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that´s what I needed.